# Cypress Input Using Class and Name

Tags: cypress

Encountering an error whenever I try to do an input using class and sd-name.

HTML is below:

```
<input class="form-control sdEventField sdGuest" name="57aeaf15f675f10d71ee" sd-field-scope="ST" sd-name="FIRST_NAME" sd-scope="IT" type="text" value="" id="57aeaf15f675f10d71ee">
```

Error is *Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: input[sd-name="FIRST_NAME"], but never found it.*

What my code is

```
cy.get('*[class^="form-control sdEventField sdGuest"]').within(() => { cy.get('input[sd-name="FIRST_NAME"]').type('Cucumber') 
        })
```

The `class="form-control sdEventField sdGuest"` is being used by several fields like last name, email, etc.,

Comment: Please add the HTML of your element to the question.

Comment: HTML is <input class="form-control sdEventField sdGuest" name="57aeaf15f675f10d71ee" sd-field-scope="ST" sd-name="FIRST_NAME" sd-scope="IT" type="text" value="" id="57aeaf15f675f10d71ee">

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your HTML is that the class `form-control sdEventField sdGuest` is part of the input element, so here you can directly use the get command. You selector selection `input[sd-name="FIRST_NAME"]` is good and correct.

```js
cy.get('input[sd-name="FIRST_NAME"]').type('Cucumber', {force: true})
```

You can use `eq(1)`, to get to the second element like this:

```js
cy.get('input[sd-name="FIRST_NAME"]').eq(1).type('Cucumber', {force: true})
```

Comment: Issue I have is `sd-name="FIRST_NAME"` is being used twice in the form. The first first name is using `class="form-control sdEventField"` while second first name is using `class="form-control sdEventField sdGuest"`

Comment: In both of the fields, is there anything different in their HTML's?

Comment: Yup, it goes something like this. First one `input class="form-control sdEventField" sd-name="FIRST_NAME"` and while second is `input class="form-control sdEventField sdGuest" sd-name="FIRST_NAME"`

Comment: Updated the answer. You can use `eq(1)` to get to the second field in the form. for the first field use `eq(0)`.

Comment: Having error still upon using it, `cy.get('input[sd-name="FIRST_NAME"]').eq(1).type('Cucumber')`

Comment: It says `<input class="form-control sdEventField sdGuest" name="9739ca523af6be32" sd-field-scope="ST" sd-name="FIRST_NAME" sd-scope="IT" type="text" value="">`

This element `<input.form-control.sdEventField.sdGuest> is not visible because its parent <div.userTypeWrapper.guest_wrapper>` has CSS property: `display: none`

Fix this problem, or use `{force: true}` to disable error checking.

Comment: You have to use `{force: true}` with `type`. Updated the answer.

Comment: I did `cy.get('input[sd-name="FIRST_NAME"]').eq(1).type('Cucumber 2', {force: true})` but the Cucumber 2 input is not being inputted still.

Answer (score 0):

You should drop this part:

```js
cy.get('*[class^="form-control sdEventField sdGuest"]').within(() => {
```

or more precisely incorporate it into the input selector

```js
cy.get('input[class="form-control sdEventField sdGuest"][sd-name="FIRST_NAME"]')
  .eq(1)
  .type('Cucumber', {force:true})
```

Using `.within()` is not meant for taking a subset of the elements, it's about parent/child relationship.

---

A better approach is to add `data-cy="FIRST_NAME1"` attributes specifically for your testing.

Comment: If you don't see the text entered, it would be because you have the wrong input (it's parent is hidden) so try `.eq(0)` instead.

Comment: No problem - for the record, which bit? Was it the change to `.eq(0)` that made the difference?